# jQuery undefined object error when initialisation code is skipped for some odd reason

Tags: javascript, jquery, skype, skype4com

I'am trying to run a Skype SDK on my site, which will allow me to log into Skype initially. The code I'am using is from https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/dn962162(v=office.16).aspx but when running the javascript through it complains of an undefined object. Here is the javascript code (ignore the $j, this is needed by us to run jQuery),

```
/**
 * This script demonstrates how to sign the user in and how to sign it out.
 */
$j(function () {
  'use strict';    // create an instance of the Application object;
  // note, that different instances of Application may
  // represent different users
  var Application
  var client;

  Skype.initialize({
    apiKey: 'SWX-BUILD-SDK',
  }, function (api) {
    Application = api.application;
    client = new Application();
  }, function (err) {
    alert('some error occurred: ' + err);
  });

  // whenever state changes, display its value
  client.signInManager.state.changed(function (state) {
    $j('#application_state').text(state);
  });

  // when the user clicks on the "Sign In" button
  $j('#signin').click(function () {
    // start signing in
    client.signInManager.signIn({
      username: $j('#username').text(),
      password: $j('#password').text()
    }).then(
      //onSuccess callback
      function () {
        // when the sign in operation succeeds display the user name
        alert('Signed in as ' + client.personsAndGroupsManager.mePerson.displayName());
      },
      //onFailure callback
      function (error) {
        // if something goes wrong in either of the steps above,
        // display the error message
        alert(error || 'Cannot sign in');
      });
  });

  // when the user clicks on the "Sign Out" button
  $j('#signout').click(function () {
    // start signing out
    client.signInManager.signOut()
      .then(
      //onSuccess callback
      function () {
        // and report the success
        alert('Signed out');
      },
      //onFailure callback
      function (error) {
        // or a failure
        alert(error || 'Cannot sign in');
      });
  });
});
```

When I run this through, it doesn't enter into the "Skype.initialize({" code but jumps to "client.signInManager.state.changed(function (state) {", which is when it throws this error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'signInManager' of undefined". When running this though the source debugger in chrome it shows that "Application" is undefined and that "client" is also undefined. So my question is why aren't these 2 objects getting initialised in the Skype.initialize code?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to add the listener, after the client is initialized. So in the initialize "success" callback. The way you have it implemented at the moment, the script tries to add the listener before the client is initialized, on an undefined object attribute, hence the error.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm new to jQuery so could you elaborate this a bit further please?